# How to get tickers on yahoo finance

Tags: yfinance, ticker

Hi I'm looking for an efficient way to get yahoo finance tickers for a data analysis project with python. I didn't found a complete list to download automatically instead of copying one to one.

I tried using the yahoo query library but it doesn't seem to have a complete list and an easy way of downloading a lot of tickers (the number of tickers that you want to download has to be less than 250).

This is the method I'm using:

```
s = yq.Screener()             
data = s.get_screeners('all_cryptocurrencies_us', 250)
dicts = data['all_cryptocurrencies_us']['quotes']
symbols = [d['symbol'] for d in dicts]
```

Comment: Read the error message and use a debugger to investigate. "String indices must be integers, not 'str'." So either `data` or `data['all_cryptocurrencies_us']` is a string. Figure out what string it is. Maybe it's explaining something.

Comment: I found that setting 251 in the function `s.get_screeners` gives that `data['all_cryptocurrencies_us']` is a string of value _size is too large_

Comment: Well there you have it, right from the horse's mouth. The API says that 251 is too large. That's why you are getting an error.